# Why smart pointer templates need to disable exception throwing in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers

I find such question while reading the *Smart Pointer Template Classes* in C++ primer plus.
The book gives an example of how *auto_ptr* class is implemented, like this,

```
template<class X> class auto_ptr {
public:
    explicit auto_ptr(X* p = 0) throw();
...};
```

throw() at the end of constructor means this constructor doesn't throw an exception.
I know this is deprecated, but I do not know why it needs to disable its exception throwing.

Comment: Note that `throw()` is deprecated and you should use `noexcept`. Also, `auto_ptr` is deprecated in favour of `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @rubenvb, yes I know, just curious the reason behind this ; )

Answer (score 5):

`throw()` doesn't disable exception throwing. It simply says that the function does not throw any exceptions. That's a statement about the code in the constructor: there's nothing there that will throw an exception that escapes from the constructor. That means that either the code in the constructor doesn't throw any exceptions (for example, `int i = 3;` will not throw an exception), or that anything that does throw an exception is enclosed in a `try` block whose `catch` clauses don't throw anything.

Comment: Good explanation, but misses OP's intent. The ideal answer would combine this with @songyuanyao's.

Comment: @YamMarcovic:  Smart pointers constructors (in general) *can* throw.  Just when they do they need to not leak their argument.  For example see the `shared_ptr(T*)` constructor.  It can throw.

Answer (score 3):

Because if the constructor of `auto_ptr` would throw exceptions, the pointer might be lost and then cause memory leak. For example:

```
auto_ptr<int> ap(new int);
```

The memory allocated couldn't be deallocated again if the constructor failed.

Comment: The absence of `throw()` does not mean that the function will throw exceptions. All it means is that the function doesn't promise not to throw exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm still wondering what gonna happen if auto_ptr's constructor fails to construct the object?

Comment: @Curtis2 - it's written so that it can't fail.

Comment: @Curtis2 If `auto_ptr`'s constructor throws an exception (just an assumption), the exception might be caught by a `try-catch` block, but in my example you couldn't do anything valuable in `catch` block. The pointer passed to it has been lost, then the memory allocated been lost either.

Comment: @PeteBecker Can't fail? I don't get it, does it mean there are some kind of mechanism that guarantee the success?

Comment: @songyuanyao So the reason we use throw() is that throwing exception can do nothing helpful here. If problem occurs, the memory leak is inevitable?

Comment: @Curtis2 - the constructor just copies the pointer that was passed in. As long as that pointer satisfies the preconditions for the constructor (i.e., it is either `NULL` or a value returned by `new T`) copying it simply won't fail.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ah~ I see. Thanks : )

Comment: @songyuanyao So it's caller's responsibility, thank your for the help. Actually, this is my first time to see a constructor using throw()/nonexcept, and still not familiar with exceptions in C++.

Comment: @songyuanyao Actually, following on Howard's point, what would stop a smart pointer constructor from just making sure that the pointer it gets never leaves it alive if it _does_ end up throwing an exception? Would there be a serious drawback in that? If so, why may `shared_ptr(T*)` throw `bad_alloc`?

Answer (score 0):

They are declaring an intent/promise not to throw exceptions - they still can, but will be smacked down hard by the runtime if they do.
The reason to use noexcept over throw() is mostly academic.